# jquery catching QUnit.done

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I catch QUnit.done from jquery.testHelper.js
https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/blob/master/tests/jquery.testHelper.js

I tried to define

```
QUnit.done = function ( failed, passed, total, runtime ) {  
    alert("test");  
 }
```

but it's giving me "Uncaught ReferenceError: QUnit is not defined"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make sure to define this after the  QUnit library is loaded. Also, the function takes one parameter which is an object `{ name, failed, passed, total }` so:

```
QUnit.done = function ( result ) {  
    alert(result.total);  
}
```